# How to prevent injections in ASP/VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, code-injection, input-filtering

What are the best ways (or at least most common ways) in ASP (VBScript) for input handling? My main concerns are HTML/JavaScript injections & SQL injections. Is there some equivalent to PHP's `htmlspecialchars` or `addslashes`, et cetera? Or do I have to do it manually with something like string replace functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bottom line is this:

1. Always HTML-encode user input before you write it to your page. `Server.HTMLEncode()` does that for you.
2. Always use parameterized queries to interface with a database. The `ÀDODB.Command` and `ADODB.CommandParameter` objects are the right choice here.
3. Always use the URLScan utility and IIS lockdown on the IIS server that renders the page, unless they are version 6 and up, which do not require these tools anymore.

If you stick to points 1 and 2 *slavishly*, I can't think of much that can go wrong.

Most vulnerabilities come from not properly encoding user input or building SQL strings from it. If you for some reason come to the point where HTML-encoding user input stands in your way, you have found a design flaw in your application.

Comment: What if your form accepted content that was going to be published via some medium other than the web -- eg a magazine.  You wouldn't want HTML-encoded characters then.  Sometimes the input has to be kept as clean and original as possible if you don't know where it will wind up.

Comment: I said: Always encode before you write it to your *page*, not before you write it to the database. This would be nonsense and is one cause for many double encoding glitches ("&amp;amp;") that can be seen on the web.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to Tomalaks list one other point.

Avoid using concatenation of field values in SQL code.  That is, in some cases a stored procedure may build some SQL in a string to subsequently execute.  This is fine unless a textual field value is used as part of its construction.

A command parameter can protect SQL code designed to input a value from being hijacked into executing unwanted SQL but it allows such unwanted SQL to become data in the database.  This is a first-level vunerability.  A second-level injection vunerability exists if the field's value is then used in some SQL string concatenation inside a stored procedure.

Another consideration is that this is just minimal protection.  All its doing is rendering attack attempts harmless.  However in many cases it may be better to add to this a system which prevents such data entry altogther and/or alters admins to a potential injection attack.

This is where input validation becomes important.  I don't know of any tools that do this for you but a few simple Regular Expressions might help.  For example, "<\w+" would detect the attempt to include a HTML tag in the field.